# Time Series forecasting in Tableau using R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, tableau-desktop

I have daily data for system performance for 1st nov 2020 , the monthly data is taken as an average of the daily data . i am trying to forecast the AVG score for next 3 months . Using tableau and r COMBINATION
Here is the script

```
SCRIPT_REAL("library(forecast);
time <- ts(.arg1.start=c(2020,11),frequency = 12);
fcast <- forecast(time, h= arg2(1));
n <- length(.arg1);
append[.arg1((.arg2(1)+1):n],fcast$mean, after = n - .arg2[1])",
AVG([Health Score]),[Periods to forecast])
```

but this is not working

An error occurred while communicating with the Analytics Extension. Error in base::parse(text = .cmd) : :5:28: unexpected ']' 4: n <- length(.arg1); 5: append[.arg1((.arg2(1)+1):n] ^

Comment: Did you meant `append(` instead of `append[` I am guessing `append(.arg1[(.arg2(1)+1):n],...`

Comment: @akrun I got this now Error in .arg2(1) : could not find function ".arg2"

Comment: Sorry, we can't test a non-reproducible example

Comment: You need a dot before arg2